# What does the breath (נְשָׁמָה) of life mean in Genesis 2:7?

Tags: genesis, human

[image]A person consists of:

1. Physical body (from the dust of the earth)
2. The breath of life (נְשָׁמָה)
3. The living soul (נֶפֶשׁ)

What does the breath of life (נְשָׁמָה) mean in Genesis 2:7?

Answer (score 1):

The three components of a person as listed by the OP is at variance with the text of Gen 2:7.  The actual text of Gen 2:7 is (NASB):

> Then the LORD God formed the man of dust from the ground, and breathed
> into his nostrils the breath of life [chay = life]; and the man became a living [chay = life]
> person [nephesh = soul].

According this verse, a person is a living being or living soul and we can summarize by saying (according to Gen 2:7)

- man formed from dust **+** breath of life **=** living being/soul

The breath of life, whatever that is, is something that mankind shares with all living creatures that breathe.  For instance:

- Gen 1:30 - all the creatures created on the sixth day have the breath of life
- Gen 6:17 - all the creatures destroyed by the flood had the breath of life
- Gen 7:22, 15 - all the animals on Noah's ark had the breath of life
- Num 16:22, 27:16 - breath of life exists in all people
- Josh 10:40 - Joshua destroyed all the cattle and animals that had the breath of life
- Eccl 3:19 - all men and beasts have the same breath of life
- Eccl 11:5 - we do not understand the breath of life

Now, according to Gen 2:7, God gives the breath of life to initiate a living being/soul.  However, at death, the breath of life returns to God who gave it, Job 34:14, Eccl 12:7.

This is confirmed by Stephen's prayer to Jesus to receive his breath at death, Acts 7:59, which essentially quotes Ps 31:5.

**CONCLUSION**

It is well-known that humans cannot create life - but God can!  The "breath of life" appears to be the difference between a dead body and a living person/soul.  Beyond that we cannot go because the Bible is silent and has no further information.

Comment: Thank for answer. How do you explain the text of Job 32:8 -The Neshama of God gives understanding?

Comment: @SebastianElishav - without the breath of God, there can be no understanding - a dead person cannot think.

Answer (score 1):

Genesis 2:7 (NKJV):

> 7 And the Lord God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living being.

We see in this that God breathed the breath of life into Adam's nostrils, resulting in his transformation into a living being.

Job 33:4 (NKJV):

> The Spirit of God has made me, And the breath of the Almighty gives me
> life.

This passage acknowledges that the breath of life comes from God, emphasizing His role as the ultimate source of human life and existence.

Psalm 104:29-30 (NKJV):

> You hide Your face, they are troubled; You take away their breath,
> they die and return to their dust. 30 You send forth Your Spirit, they
> are created; And You renew the face of the earth.

Here, the psalmist recognizes that God's Spirit and breath are essential for both creation and the preservation of life.

Ecclesiastes 12:7 (NKJV):

> Then the dust will return to the earth as it was, And the spirit will
> return to God who gave it.

This passage addresses the duality of human existence, where the mortal body goes back to the ground while the spirit (or breath of life) ascends to God upon passing.

Job 32:8 (NKJV):

> 8 But there is a spirit in man, And the breath of the Almighty gives
> him understanding.

This passage shows that without the "breath," there is no understanding.

**The KJV translates Strong's H5397 in the following manner:** breath (17x), blast (3x), spirit (2x), inspiration (1x), souls (1x).

**Outline of Biblical Usage**

breath, spirit

breath (of God)

breath (of man)

every breathing thing

spirit (of man)

**Strong’s Definitions (Strong’s Definitions Legend)**

**נְשָׁמָה nᵉshâmâh, nesh-aw-maw'; from H5395;** a puff, i.e. wind, angry or vital breath, divine inspiration, intellect. or (concretely) an animal:—blast, (that) breath(-eth), inspiration, soul, spirit.

---

The concept of "breath of life" (נְשָׁמָה, neshamah) signifies the vital force or essence of life that God breathed into Adam, bringing him to life and making him a living being.

This divine act of breathing is the source for the infusion of life and understanding into Adam's physical body, transforming him from a lifeless form made of dust into a living, breathing being.

The breath of life (neshamah) along with the spirit (ruach) represents the spiritual aspect of human existence, the divine spark that distinguishes humans from the rest of creation. It signifies the close connection between God and humanity, as well as the inherent worth and dignity of human life given by God. This divine breath is often considered to be what animates and sustains human life, allowing individuals to live, move, and possess consciousness.

> And the human kind is heavily related to God because only God and
> humans possess neshama! That’s the meaning of “God created humans in
> His Image after His Likeness.” [[1]](https://theexplanation.com/living-soul-fascinating-meaning-man-and-animal/)

Moreover, the breath of life conveys a sense of reliance on God for life and to be sustained. Without it, we cannot live. It also shows the Creator's authority over life and death, as well as our responsibility to God as the origin of our being. The  breath of life reveals the spiritual aspect of human beings and their special bond with their Creator.